# Error in Clipping Polygon

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing

I tried Clipping my polygon after union but it gave me this error:

```
QGIS version: 3.26.0-Buenos Aires
QGIS code revision: 0aece2818e
Qt version: 5.15.3
Python version: 3.9.5
GDAL version: 3.5.0
GEOS version: 3.10.3-CAPI-1.16.1
PROJ version: Rel. 9.0.1, June 15th, 2022
PDAL version: 2.3.0 (git-version: 988ee3)
Algorithm started at: 2023-01-14T13:15:12
Algorithm 'Clip' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'INPUT' : 'memory://MultiPolygonZ?crs=USER:100000&field=fid:long(0,0)&field=LAYER_2:string(254,0)&field=fid_2:long(0,0)&uid={2542546f-da71-45dc-a74e-8c76fcc2a509}', 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'OVERLAY' : 'memory://MultiPolygonZ?crs=USER:100000&field=fid:long(0,0)&field=PhaseName:string(50,0)&field=area:double(0,0)&field=perimeter:double(0,0)&uid={d86fda25-378a-4f44-968d-a618ea3b1935}' }

No spatial index exists for input layer, performance will be severely degraded
GEOS geoprocessing error: intersection failed.


Execution failed after 0.07 seconds

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Clip' finished
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct input layers? Try Clip again and select/set them. Sometime tool dialoges doesnt use the correct ones when you have temp layers

Comment: yes I am sure. It does all the time.  Thank you for your help